# The SourceSet 'robolectric' is not recognized by the Android Gradle Plugin

Tags: android, android-studio, robolectric, robolectric-gradle-plugin

Updated to Android Studio 3.1 and its corresponding gradle. I'm getting a message when trying to sync "The SourceSet 'robolectric' is not recognized by the Android Gradle Plugin. Perhaps you misspelled something?".

Here is the current sourceSet in the gradle file:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
    }
    robolectric {
        java.srcDir file('src/test/java/')
        resources.srcDir file('src/test/resources')
    }
}
```

Comment: did you find answer? if so, please post it here..

Answer (score 0):

The defined `sourceSet` must match an already defined `buildType` or `productFlavor`. This excludes `main` which is defined by default.

```
buildTypes {
        debug {
           //TODO: Your buildType config here
        }

        robolectric {
           //TODO: Your buildType config here
        }
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
    }
    robolectric {
        java.srcDir file('src/test/java/')
        resources.srcDir file('src/test/resources')
    }
}
```