# How to add source set to android project

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

In my android project I want to add an additional `sourceSet` aside with the default android source sets (main, debug...)

In my `build.gradle` file I have tried the following:

```
android {
...
    sourceSet {
        create("shuttle")
    }
....
}
```

unfortunately I get this error when I sync/build the project
`ERROR: The SourceSet 'shuttle' is not recognized by the Android Gradle Plugin. Perhaps you misspelled something?`

Any ideas how to create android source sets that will appear under `src/{sourceSetName}` directory like the way I see `src/main`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Android does not allow you to define custom sourcesets anymore. The default sourcesets are: `main`, `debug` and `release` and if you really want another one, you could add a buildtype or a flavor for which android then creates an accompanying sourceset.
Also see my other answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73231777/3968618
And someone else's example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61810433/3968618

Comment: Any know reasons of such brilliant architectural decision?